# Colors in Bootstrap custom download?

Tags: css, colors, twitter-bootstrap, less

So I'm using the Bootstrap [Customize and Download page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html) to generate a version of the Bootstrap files with custom colors. I got the idea that I wanted to add some other colors (e.g. @purpleLight) to make upkeep of the site design easier, so I look through the downloaded contents the site generates, and my customizations don't appear to be anywhere, let alone somewhere for me to add others.
Here's what comes in the bootstrap.zip the site spits out:

- css

  - bootstrap.css
  - bootstrap.min.css
- img

  - glyphicons-halflings.png
  - glyphicons-halflings-white.png
- js

  - bootstrap.js
  - bootstrap.min.js

...and that's it.
So, no colors anywhere in these files as far as I can tell. No LESS files included in the download. Am I doing something wrong? Is the site doing something wrong? Am I just not seeing something that is in fact there? To the best of my diffing abilities, the downloads seem identical regardless of the customization options I choose...

And, pending whose messing up here, what would be the alternative best way for me to customize a color palette for my Bootstrap site?

Comment: I think you need to obtain the full repository to get the source files including LESS files. Customized download gives you only the compiled and minified versions.

Comment: Well, right I understand that, my question is, without those, what exactly is customized? And where are said customizations found? If I download my "custom" version then go download the repository it doesn't magically have my custom shade of blue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add more LESS variables with the custom download tool. You can only redefine the values of the existing variables. Upon download, the tool compiles with those set variables but since you don't get the LESS files, you won't be able to add more variables afterwards, like @purpleLight you mentioned.

If you want to extend Bootstrap with more LESS variables, you have to download the [full source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/) and compile your css from the included LESS files. There's a file `variables.less` in the `less/` folder where can add your @purpleLight.

Comment: So, just for complete knowledge, where exactly are the redefined existing values in those custom files? I tried stuff like GREPping for "C3ACD3" and found nothing,,,

Comment: They should be in the `bootstrap.css` & `bootstrap.min.css`. Example: put in for @linkColor: #000. Click Download. From the downloaded package open css/bootstrap.css in an editor. On line 142-149 you'll find the declaration for `a` and `a:hover` with the custom color.

Comment: *OH* ok, so I completely misunderstood what the customizer was doing. I was thinking that, whatever color I put in there would let me use \@blue as that color throughout my Bootstrap site, but what really happening is that I'm defining a value of \@blue for the compiler to use for that specific stylesheet, so that .navbar-search will use my custom \@blue color or whatever. Now those downloads make a lot more sense. Still not sure why my grep failed though :(. Thanks for the help!

Comment: All correct, and no problem :-) You could open an issue on github and suggest the inclusion of the less files for the custom download tool.

Comment: I did just that. Thanks again for your help.