# combining initializer with custom bootstrap and stylebootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, customization, html5boilerplate

I would like to start an html5 boilerplate project, with a customized bootstrap (elements) and custom styled bootstrap (css) using a web interface. How can I achieve this?
I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125447/colors-in-bootstrap-custom-download) that I would have to compile locally. But how can I get a GUI to select the components I want then? And how can I include the [stylebootstrap](http://stylebootstrap.info/) functionality? When you use these websites, you either use [bootstrap's customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html) or stylebootstrap. And if I want my bootstrap intgrated in html boilerplate, their site only offers the default version, without any customisation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to copy and paste the code generated by stylebootstrap.

Read all the CSS and see if you can tell which selectors are relevant to your page. You might find that doing it without Bootstrap would be easier.

There might be GUI generators but IMO those are just going to add complexity if you are not clear on the basics.